# Is cellular automata something that is studied in mathematics departments?

Tags: soft-question, cellular-automata

I am interested in studying cellular automata but am unsure if I should be looking at CS or mathematics graduate departments. Symbolic dynamics seems to have some tie to cellular automata but I haven't really found anything else really specific. There was maybe one Harvard faculty member that listed cellular automata as an interest as well. Any related fields or specific schools/researchers would be a great help as well.

Comment: No (unless things changed terribly a lot in the very last years in some universities)

Comment: While there are fairly broad fields in mathematics about which it might be said that many departments will have research faculty working in that area, as you begin to look at narrowed fields the fraction of departments that could be interested in the production of graduate students/dissertations in that area drops quickly.  It's a good idea to shop carefully if your interests are already so focused.

Comment: I was able to find [one](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/research/profiles/?fac_id=gravner) at UC Davis.

Comment: This question has also been asked at [Academia.SE](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/32778/in-what-department-is-cellular-automata-studied).

Comment: You are just speaking about USA I guess...

Answer (score 3):

Symbolic dynamics has cellular automata as a subfield, so anybody working in symbolic dynamics is a candidate for also having interest in CAs. In the US/Canada I would try:
Mike Boyle in Maryland
Natasha Jonoska in Florida
Maurice Margenstern
Brian Marcus in UBC, Vancouver
Marcus Pivato in Peterborough

In Europe many people work on CAs as well:
Jarrko Kari in Turku, Finland
Tullio Ceccherini-Silberstein in Rome
Jean Mairesse, Guillaume Theyssier, Nicolas Ollinger, Enrico Formenti all in France, also people in Marseille and other universities in France

In Southamerica:
Alejandro Maass, Michael Schraudner and Eric Goles in Santiago de Chile

Also people in China and Asia (but I am not very familiar with their work).

For sure I forgot several people, but at least you get an idea...

A good place to find names of people interested in CAs is to take a book on CAs and look at its references or to search for related papers on arxiv or mathscinet.